# Laravel Horizon - gate with different guard

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-horizon

I would like to use admin guard for authorise viewing laravel horizon but I have to be logged in as user AND as admin.

Here is my code for HorizonServiceProvider.php

```
class HorizonServiceProvider extends HorizonApplicationServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        // Horizon::routeSmsNotificationsTo('15556667777');
        // Horizon::routeMailNotificationsTo('example@example.com');
        // Horizon::routeSlackNotificationsTo('slack-webhook-url', '#channel');

        // Horizon::night();
    }

    /**
     * Register the Horizon gate.
     *
     * This gate determines who can access Horizon in non-local environments.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function gate()
    {
        Gate::define('viewHorizon', function () {
            return \Auth::guard('admin')->check();
        });
    }
}
```

It works OK if I am logged in as used AND admin. But when I am logged in only as admin the result from gate is:

```
array:4 [▼
  "ability" => "viewHorizon"
  "result" => null
  "user" => null
  "arguments" => "[0 => null]"
]
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Correct this line`It works OK if I am logged in as used AND admin. But when I am logged in only as admin the result from gate is:` doesn't seems meaningful.

Comment: It means that if I am logged in with user guard and admin guard I can access horizon, If I am logged in with admin guard I get 403 when I access horizon

Answer (score 4):

Probably too little too late for you, but for others searching the issue:

Laravel assumes that you use the default "web" guard and it is injecting the authenticated user (so it forces the "web" guard check).

As specified in the docs (see big "!" note), to force Laravel to not require "web" guard authentication you just need to specify `$user = null`, and then you can implement whatever you want.

So your case the gate function in the `HorizonServiceProvider` class should be something like this:

```
protected function gate() {

    Gate::define('viewHorizon', function ($user = null) {
        return Auth::guard('admin')->check();
    });

}
```

Comment: Also not that if you want to check the gate behaviour locally, you should switch your env (APP_ENV) to "production" as the gate always allows access if your env is set to "local". (it says so on the gate function "This gate determines who can access Horizon in **non-local** environment")